# Configurable Lua formatter

Tags: lua

We recently added some policies to out fairly large Lua project, which also includes some stricter style guidelines than we used to.
The problem we are facing now is to convert the whole codebase to the new style guidelines, which is a lot of work. I started reformatting the code and got tired of it after about 5 files out of hundreds.

My idea is to use a code formatter, which automatically does this for me. However, the output format needs to be according to our style guidelines and not any different style. We also have some unusual guidelines, like a space before the opening parenthesis for the argument list in a function definition.

All this makes it fairly hard to find a suitable formatter. Does anyone know about one that meets all my criteria? Any help will be greatly appreciated.